# Tailwind resize input arrow buttons

Tags: input, tailwind-css

I have a number input, whose arrow buttons I am trying to resize. I found that I am able to access them via the element's class as below:

```
<input v-model="vMin" type="number" class="input w-20
[appearance:textfield] [&::-webkit-outer-spin-button]:appearance-none [&::-webkit-inner-spin-button]:appearance-none" />
```

The above code works, as the arrows disappear. When I try to change the appearance-none to any other class though, they don't show up either. Changing the [appearance:textfield] to [class I am using:textfield], makes them show up, but completely unchanged.

I tried out several classes and none of them make any (visible) changes. It's a Laravel/Vue app, if that makes any difference.

Any ideas on how I could resize these arrow buttons?